# vertical-align: middle doesn't work

Tags: html, css

The css property `vertical-align: middle` does not work in this example.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class='twoline'>Two line text</span>
  <span class='float'>  Float right  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.float {
    float: right;
}

.twoline {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The `span` that is floating on the right is not vertically centered with respect to its containing `div`.  How can I have it vertically centered?

The above code is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/1/).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You must wrap your element in a `table-cell`, within a `table` using `display`.

Like this:

```
<div>
  <span class='twoline'>Two line text</span>
  <span class='float'>Float right</span>
</div>
```

and

```
.float {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
}
.twoline {
    width: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
}
div {
    display: table;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/7/

Comment: This works just fine *without* setting a fixed height: http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/9/ (Your solution implies that the DIV has to have a fixed height in order for it to work... )

Comment: The extra height simply makes it easier to see that the element is indeed vertically centered, nothing more. I thought my explanation would be sufficient enough.

Comment: Is it necessary for parent to have `display: table`? Because I tested this scenario in FF without it and it works.

Comment: According to the specs `display: table;` makes the element behave like a `<table>` and [defines a block-level box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). So it will probably work without explicitly declaring the parent as `display: table;` as long as the parent it a block-level box element, but semantically it's proper to wrap table elements in a table.

Comment: Usually when I google this I realize that I really just want to use `margin: auto;` on the element I want centered. Usually much better than dealing with table-cells in my opinion.

Comment: @pixelpax That will not align the element vertically. Maybe only if you're using flexbox.

Answer (score 11):

Vertical align doesn't quite work the way you want it to. See: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

This isn't pretty, but it WILL do what you want: Vertical align behaves as expected only when used in a table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/e8ESb/6/

There are other alternatives: You can declare things as tables or table cells within CSS to make them behave as desired, for example. Margins and positioning can sometimes be played with to get the same effect. None of the solutions are terrible pretty, though.

Comment: it's very, very far from "very very difficult". you can just add the CSS display property to render the table-like structure needed for vertical-align to work.

Comment: Okay, in THIS case, at least, its not difficult. I've taken that out. There are other situations where it can very quickly become more difficult than you would expect, though.

Answer (score 10):

You should set a fixed value to your span's `line-height` property:

```
.float, .twoline {
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This can be tidy solution when the container height is fixed - provided that text content absolutely, positively will never wrap.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by Matt K works perfectly fine.

However it is important to note one thing - 
If the div you are applying it to has absolute positioning, it wont work. For it to work, do this -

```
<div style="position:absolute; hei...">
   <div style="position:relative; display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; hei..."> 
      <!-- here position MUST be relative, this div acts as a wrapper-->
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```