# Vertical align center not working inside Bootstrap container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39748/

I want the text `Hello World` to be centered vertical but somehow it is not working. How do I fix this problem?

This is my CSS:

```
.app-header{
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.v-center{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967217/vertical-align-middle-doesnt-work. You must wrap your element in a table-cell, within a table using display.

Comment: May this be of assistance: 

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39749/

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Flex solution: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39748/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can do this with many different ways.

One way is to use `display:flex;` together with `align-items:center`.

See below

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.app-header{
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container {
  width:100%;
}
.v-center{
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="app-header">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right v-center">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

That would be a responsive solution meaning that no matter the height of the header, the text will be vertically aligned in the center of it.

Another solution would be to set the `line-height` of the `v-center` equal to your header height, in your case `.v-center { line-height:50px}`

Answer (score 2):

Set `line-height` to the div `height`.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.app-header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.v-center {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px; /* .app-header div height */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-header">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right v-center">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a line-height as the same height of the header:

```
.v-center{
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

This way you can keep on using bootstrap framework classes without introducing flexbox or absolute positioning.

Updated codepen here: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/MOqWwP

Comment: if you set the line-height, you don;t need the `vertical-align:middle` style

Comment: @MihaiT thanks for the hint! I've updated the codepen!

Answer (score 1):

Give `line-height:50px;` to `.v-center` class.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.app-header{
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.v-center{
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:50px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-header">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right v-center">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```